Shortcut to arithmetically code numbers with geometric distribution of probabilities?
I would like to arithmetically encode arbitrary-valued integers.
The probability of an integer having a value N is P*(1-P)^N.  If P is 1/10, then p(0) = 0.1, p(1) = 0.09, p(2) = 0.081, etc.
In the special case of P = 0.5 Huffman coding would be 100% efficient.
Otherwise I believe that arithmetic encoding would be more efficient.
Does having a geometric distribution of probabilities allow any shortcuts in arithmetic coding?
